# Laravel can not upload files with id to database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload file with user id to database, but I have a trouble.
NotFoundHttpException

Here's my code:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/uploaded', $client->id,  'files' => true)) !!}

{!!Form::file('image') !!}

{!!Form::submit('Upload File') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and web.php

```
Route::post('uploaded/{id}/', 'FileController@uploaded');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url should be

```
Form::open(array('url' => '/uploaded/'.$client->id,'files' => true)) !!}
```

Then only that route will work, which you should have defined in web.